# Restrict user to do SFTP on the www folder owned by www-data group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, useradd, wordpress

I would like to create a new user with read/write privileges ONLY in the /var/www/ directory including all sub-directories. The /var/www/ is owned by a group called www-data.

Best way to do it I guess is with SFTP. I already have SSH access as root.
 Many other answers relating to restricting SFTP access are related to the /home/ directory and require to change ownership of directory to root and I don't know if it's a good idea to do that also on the www directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user, set its home directory to /var/www/ and add him to the www-data group. If you want the files he will create belongs to the www-data group, you'll have to add the "s" bit to the www directory's mod.

```
# useradd -m /var/www -g www-data
# chmod g+s /var/www
```

Or did I missunderstand the question? Maybe you want that this user can't read any other directory? In this case you can `chroot` him:
http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-automatically-chroot-jail-selected-ssh-user-logins

If you want to use SFTP: https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/

s bit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Special_modes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: Yes I want to do both chroot the /www directory and use SFTP, but the problem is that I don't know if it's a good idea to do that on /www.   All solutions I have seen so far always refer to new directories created for that purpose, not an existing /www directory wich already has wordpress on it.

Comment: thanks for those great links. I'll `chroot` the user, but to do that seems that I have to change ownership of the `www` to `root`.  Is it ok to do that?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: According to all the literature I've read, also in your first link... "every folder leading up to and including the home folder must be owned by root, otherwise you will get the following error after logging in:"

`Write failed: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer`  In my case is not the /home folder but the /www   EDIT: your second link.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Well you can chown root, but make sure that www-data has the right to write. Otherwise Wordpress will not work. If you keep www-data group + chmod 775 it should work.

Comment: Than you very much! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use the chroot feature of sshd and the sftp subsystem.

Given a `DocumentRoot` setting of `/var/www-sites/example.com/html`

Create a group, named something like "chrootwebusers"

`root@hostname:~# addgroup chrootwebusers`

Add a user and set their home directory and some other options -

```
useradd -g chrootwebusers -d /var/www-sites/example.com -s /bin/false theusername
mkdir -p /var/www-sites/example.com/html
chown theusername.www-data /var/www-sites/example.com
chmod -R 750 /var/www-sites/example.com
chmod g+s /var/www-sites/example.com
passwd theusername
```

This adds the user named `theusername` with group membership in your `chrootwebusers` group, with a home directory of /var/www-sites/example.com and read/write access to everything below it.

The `chmod g+s /var/www-sites/example.com` works with the www-data group being the owning group.  The use of the `setgid` bit on a directory makes any new files/directories created inside of it to keep the same group ownership as the `example.com` directory.  This means the user the webserver runs as will always be able to read the files all the way down (**be aware of this!**)

Next, edit the `/etc/ssh/ssdh_config` file.  Fine the line that specifies the sftp subsystem and comment it out-

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

And add in a reference to the internal-to-sshd sftp subsystem

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Finally, at the bottom of the file add

```
Match Group chrootwebusers
    ChrootDirectory /var/www-sites
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0027
```

So... how does this all work?  The `sshd` internal-sftp subsystem waits for a login from someone who has membership in the `chrootwebusers` group.  When that happens, it will chroot them so that what you see as `/var/www-sites` they see as `/` .  They will be able to see the example.com directory, and change into it and read/write files both there and in the `DocumentRoot` of `/var/www-sites/example.com/html` - but they will see it all as `/example.com/html`.  The `-u 0027` option sets the umask so any new files/directories created will have 640/750 permissions, and the `setgid` trick we used previously will make the owning user be `theusername` and the owning group the `www-data` user (remember the bit about the webserver being able to read all the files)